# Difference between Chow break and forecast test

Tags: econometrics, chow-test

I understand that the Chow break test and the Chow forecast tests are different :

To  my understanding ,  if we had a sample with k regressors and we wanted to see whether the marginal effect of one of the regressors  on the dependent variable depends on the level of the regressor then we could split the sample in two groups where one group has the regresssor at stake with values below a threshold level and conversely for the other group and then the Chow break test would measure any difference between the effect of regressor k in the two groups with:
$$F= \frac{(\text{sum residuals complete model} - \text{sum residuals group 1} - \text{sum residuals group 2})/k}{(\text{sum residuals group 1} + \text{sum residuals group 2})/(n_1+n_2-2k)},$$
where $n_1$ and $n_2$ are the number of observations in each splited sample. If we reject, then the relationship for both levels of the considered regressor and the dependent variable are the same.

On the other side, the Chow forecast test measures whether if we estimated the unrestricted model and the model with one of the levels of the regressor at stake restricted, the relationship would be the same if we fail to reject
$$F= \frac{(\text{sum residual restricted} - \text{sum residuals unrestricted}/n_2}{\text{sum residuals unrestricted}/(n_1-k)}$$
Is my understanding correct? When do you guys use one or the other? If someone could elaborate more on the fundamental or intuitive difference I would be very thankful.